# Why values from .env file are empty?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I opened my old application

```
# php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.5.18
```

and testing it on my local laptop and on remote server(ubuntu 18 in both cases )
I suddenly found that some variables from .env file, like :

```
UPLOADS_CMSITEM_IMAGES_URL = 'uploads/cms_items/'
UPLOADS_CMSITEM_IMAGES_DIR = 'uploads/cms_items/'

UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL = 'uploads/categories/'
UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_DIR = 'uploads/categories/'
```

and calling it in my model I have empty value

```
public static function getCategoryUrl(int $category_id, string $img, bool $check_existing= false) : string
{
    if ( empty($img) ) return '';
    $base_url= with(new Settings)->getBaseUrl();
    $UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL= env('UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL');
```

and  my path is invalid...

I run

```
php artisan config:cache
```

several times, but UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL returns empty value...

How it can be and how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a config to access your `.env` values. The command `php artisan config:cache` is meant to refresh those config files (found in the 'config' folder). You can add it to `/config/app.php` for simplicity.

**/config/app.php**

```
...
'uploads_category_image_url' => env('UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL', '[some default value]'),
...
```

**In your model**

```
...
$UPLOADS_CATEGORY_IMAGES_URL = config('app.uploads_category_image_url');
...
```

One thing to note, you can use a default value if it is the same across multiple environments. This makes it easier to initially setup a new environment and also ensures you never have an unset config value within your code.